# JavaScript check if dropdown options are all disabled

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu with all options disabled except the first one which has no value (just a label). How can i check on $(document).ready(function() if all options of this dropdown option are disabled (except the first option which has no value) and if so show an alert for example alert ('All Options Disabled');.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<select id="selectId">

<option value="">Select a Car</option>

<option value="volvo"disabled>Volvo</option>

<option value="saab"disabled>Saab</option>

<option value="opel"disabled>Opel</option>

<option value="audi" disabled>Audi</option>

</select>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `option`s and check to see if every option is either disabled or whose `value` property is the empty string:

```js
const allDisabled = Array.prototype.every.call(
  document.querySelector('#selectId > option')
  option => option.disabled || option.value === ''
);
console.log(allDisabled);
```

```html
<select id="selectId">
  <option value="">Select a Car</option>
  <option value="volvo"disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab"disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel"disabled>Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" disabled>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Or, with jQuery and `each`:

```js
let allDisabled = true;
$('#selectId > option').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  if (!$this.prop('disabled') && $this.prop('value')) allDisabled = false;
});
console.log(allDisabled);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectId">
  <option value="">Select a Car</option>
  <option value="volvo"disabled>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab"disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="opel"disabled>Opel</option>
  <option value="audi" disabled>Audi</option>
</select>
```